# about cling,after switching WIFI, Often connected to the device

Tags: cling, android-cling

about cling,after switching WIFI, Often connected to the device,TV side received the news,but can not find the phone,"Device not found" error

Answer (score 0):

1,find androidRouter class,then find onNetworkTypeChange(); can resolve search history repeat.
2,AndroidUpnpServiceConfiguration createNetworkAddressFactory(),return super.createNetworkAddressFactory(65500)
   //如果网络变化 并且是WiFi情况下 那么重置
        if (newNetwork!=null && newNetwork.isConnected() && isWifi()){
            // TODO: 2017/7/19 网络变化重置路由地址和localdevice 删除历史记录  CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE这个监听有点慢 可以考虑换network_change_action
            Log.e("AndroidRouter", "onNetworkTypeChange: 调用" );
            disable();
            //清理历史记录
            List remoteDevices = UpnpServiceManager.getInstance().getRemoteDevices();
            for (int i = 0; i